# VIP emails being deleted

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have searched online but not found the answer to this problem.

For some reason, the emails in VIP folders only remain in the folder for 2 weeks and then they are gone. The oldest emails in the VIP folders are from June 16.

Is there a setting in Mac Mail for when these emails in the VIP folders are deleted?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You've got two answers, and at least one looks very helpful. Now's the time to comment below them, say if they help or not, etc. so the rest of the community knows whether you've solved your problem or not.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences > Rules. See if any rule is deleting VIP messages.[image]

If any rules rules are deleting VIP messages, Just delete Them.

[image]

Comment: Please Comment if this doesn’t work.

Comment: It's really Preferences->Rules, but no worries.

Answer (score 1):

I too, lost my VIP folder, did some research and found a solution that worked.

Locate an email (any email) from someone you'd like to mark as VIP in Apple Mail.  Hover over that person's name in the from field — it doesn't actually say "from" but it should be obvious what I'm referring to — the name above the "to" field.  A gray outline of a star should appear ... click this star and your VIP folder should reappear below your Inbox(es) and above your "flagged" and "sent" folders in the left margin of your viewer window.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you set up a "rule" in your Mail.app that automatically deletes VIP emails. Inside the mail app, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open `Preferences` then go to the `Rules` tab, and press the "Edit" button with each created rule selected.

Here's an example rule you might have created (accidentally or purposefully) that could auto-delete VIP emails:

[image: VIP Deletion rule]

Be sure to delete any such rules, then see if your problem goes away.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer given by Suryan?